# Deploying Connected App - Copado Deployment error "consumer key is already taken" Unable to upload correct yaml file

Tags: deployment, connected-apps, regular-expressions

I am trying to deploy a connected app to higher orgs through Copado but am getting the error as **"Consumer key is already taken"** and so for that am trying to create a yaml and upload it in the pipeline record (as of my knowledge this approach will help to resolve error) but am unable to create a correct yaml structure...

Please check below yaml structure which i am trying with.
Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks!!

```
regex_lib:
  remove-simple-tag: '((?ms)<consumerKey>(.+?)<\/consumerKey>)'
  
rules:
  remove-consumer-Key:
      extensions:
       - ConnectedApp
      regex_name: remove-simple-tag
      branches:
      replace_values:
       - '(?ms)<consumerKey>(.+?)<\/consumerKey>'
      replace_with:
```

Comment: SFSE can provide information about the mechanics of Connected Apps, but the details of Copado configuration are better answered by their support as it is a third-party product.

Comment: SFSE? can you provide exact link on where to reach them? Thanks!!
Also, this is NOT a copado error, even in ANT or some other deploying tools also we are getting same error for connected apps.

Comment: SFSE is Salesforce Stack Exchange, the site you are on right now. If you'd like to ask this community a question about how Connected Apps work, feel free to [edit] your post.

Comment: @sfdcfox, firstly thanks for ur approach, but we have connected apps getting deployed every now and then as per requirement, so we need some permanent solution in the deployment phase.

Comment: @VamshiReddy To be clear, you can't have the same consumer key on two different Connected Apps in two different orgs. Imagine you had the *exact same username* in two different orgs. How would Salesforce (or any platform that uses unique login ids) know which org/user you meant? As such, you cannot use the same consumer key in two different orgs, even between sandboxes and production orgs. They are unique "logins" for the purposes of Connected Apps usage.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, I am aware of it, as i said in my post above, am using yaml to exclude the consumer key while deploying, so that the consumer key wont go into the higher org... please check this link for yaml https://github.com/CopadoSolutions/Copado-Manual/blob/master/Copado.yml

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the tools, but I believe it should be:

```
rules:
  remove-consumer-Key:
      extensions:
       - connectedApp
      regex_name: 'remove-simple-tag'
      branches:
      replace_values:
       - consumerKey
      replace_with:
```

I am presuming case sensitivity for all of the parameters. This should likely give you the desired effect.

Comment: @sfdcfox- Thanks for your help, I am able to deploy my Connected apps now, I had to also change the regex lib and then it worked along with your Correct rule.

Answer (score 0):

regex_lib:

remove-simple-tag: '(?s)(\n\s*<***REPLACEVALUE***>[\s\S]*?</***REPLACEVALUE***>)'

rules:

remove-all-consumerKey:

extensions:

- connectedApp

regex_name: 'remove-simple-tag'

replace_values:

- consumerKey

replace_with:

branches: